# Set camera angle react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs

How do I point the camera to a certain direction in my scene using `react-three-fiber`? The canvas element has a camera prop but it doesn't provide a way to set the angle.

```
    <Canvas camera={{ fov: 75, position: [-10, 45, 20]}}>
```

Comment: No this does not answer my question, I'm asking how to do this using a package called `react-three-fiber` which has no documentation about this. I'm not talking about how to do it in `three.js` which is the underlying library. Could you guys be any quicker in closing questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get access to the underlying three.js camera object through the [`useThree`](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/API/hooks#state-properties) hook.

Setting the rotation property on the camera of the canvas element didn't seem to do anything so it may be reset by something else in my test scene.

Bear in mind, R3F is a [very thin wrapper over three.js](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber#can-it-keep-up-with-frequent-updates-to-threejs).  All of the documentation that applies to three.js applies to R3F as well.

> There is no hard dependency on a particular Threejs version, it does
> not wrap or duplicate a single Threejs class. It merely expresses
> Threejs in JSX: `<mesh />` becomes new `THREE.Mesh()`, and that
> happens dynamically.

```
import { Canvas, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import * as THREE from 'three';

const Scene = () => {
  useThree(({ camera }) => {
    camera.rotation.set(THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(30), 0, 0);
  });
  
  return <Canvas />;
};
```

Comment: You can not use hook outside canvas 
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/accessing-the-camera-in-react-three-fiber-out-of-the-canvas/39137

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use [useThree](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/API/hooks#state-properties) hook.
You just need to add `rotation={[30,0,0]}` or any other values, just like what you did with the position.
react-three/fiber could be very tricky, so may need to reset your app to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best answer, but for me adding rotation={[0,0,0]} to the camera helps (you have to find what is the best angle for you changing the numbers).